# Exporting as war from eclipse and add additional files

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, war

Assume there is a dynamic project.
I have a file e.g. `FileX` under the Project's directory i.e. outside of all source files etc.
E.g. `ProjectA`

If I export as WAR the `ProjectA.war` and open it I see of course the `WEB-INF` etc.
How can I include `FileX` in this export process so that `FileX` is included in the `ProjectA` dir along with `WEB-INF` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have eclipse generate the equivalent ant file to generate the WAR, you can them modify that ant file to include what you want.

This can be done by right click on the project > export > General > Ant buildfiles. Make sure you uncheck the 'use eclipse compiler' if you want the build file to be usable from outside of eclipse.